# Android: Fragment Stacks Screen Rotation / Configuration Changed

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a problem with dealing with multiple fragments and configuration changes. It goes like this

```
Container Activity

Stack:
[Fragment 1] (replace)-> [Fragment 2] (Screen rotation occurs) [Fragment 1 is visible]
```

So obviously I would like Fragment 2 to be visible than Fragment 1 after screen rotation. Is there anyway to do this? Right now I am adding Fragment 1 to the back stack after I add Fragment 2, but it doesn't seem to help at all. Should I take a completely different approach so I can get over this problem?

Current fragment transaction code:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Done but it's not going to help I think, this is more of need a example ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is going to recreate the fragments for you, after the orientation change. If you are creating a Fragment1 in Activity.onCreate() without checking if its bundle already contains the saved one: `if(savedInstanceState == null) { //create the fragment }` you may be ending up displaying a new instance of Fragment1 each time the orientation changes.

And make sure you commit the fragment trasaction from the Activity. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

But, im just guessing here because you didn't post enough code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the scope of "post code" I'll look at the solution in a little bit thanks

Comment: So that means internal (fragment) stack state is also saved.